# SQL get all names that have their MAX() where month='jan'

Tags: sql, max

I'm searching a SQl query that gives me all values that have their max() at a certain time.

This is my simplified table:

```
    +---------+-------+-------+
    | name    | value | month |
    +---------+-------+-------+
    |  joe    |   10  | jan   |
    |  olivia |   300 | jan   |
    |  tim    |   10  | jan   |
    |  joe    |   100 | feb   |
    |  olivia |   50  | feb   |
    |  tim    |   100 | feb   |
    +---------+-------+-------+
```

This is how I would describe my query:

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE MAX(value) is in 'jan'
```

This should be my result:

```
olivia
```

Best
Joerg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.value = (select max(t2.value) from t t2 where t2.name = t.name) and
      t.month = 'jan';
```

You can also use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(value) over (partition by name) as max_value
      from t
     ) t
where value = max_value and month = 'jan'
```

Answer (score 1):

you need below

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE value = (select max(value) from table where month='jan') and month='jan'
```

incase of month wise max

```
select t1.* from table_name t1
where value = (select max(value) from table_name t2 where t1.month=t2.month)
```

Comment: You need a correlated subquery.

Comment: @jarlh is olivia his expected result?

Comment: If the table also had the row (charlie, 300, October), it would be returned.

Comment: @jarlh i have added another and condition for month